# Mapping an JAXB To Oracle Type

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans, soap

I created a web service in netbeans from wsdl. for a complex type a custom java class (JAXB) was created, I need to pass this value to an oracle type in a procedure
This is my code

```
         public static Clob select (HeaderReq hdReq, String utility, String barcode,String client) throws SQLException {

        String query = "{? = Call ws.select (?,?,?,?)}";

        callableStatement = conn.getInstance (). getCon (). prepareCall (query);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter (1, OracleTypes.CLOB);
        callableStatement.setObject (2, hdReq);
        callableStatement.setString (3, utility);
        callableStatement.setString (4, barcode);
        callableStatement.setString (5, client);
        callableStatement.executeQuery ();
 return callableStatement.getClob (1);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println (ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

hdReq throws me a column type error and  I try this but it did not work

```
     JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance (HeaderReq.class);
     Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller ();

    m.setProperty (Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // To format XML

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter ();
    m.marshal (hdReq, sw);
    xmlString = sw.toString ();

    callableStatement.setObject (2, xmlString);
```